# Висит браузер при длительном нахождении на сайте

Tags: html, php, css

Заметил, что, если долго не закрывать эту страничку, то начинает виснуть браузер, при чем, это скорее всего из-за слайдера, может ли такое быть и как это исправить?
http://spfireworks.16mb.com/

Answer (score 3):

У меня такое случилось, когда я делал setInterval() вместо setTimeout(). Получалось, что в конце каждого интервала, я ещё раз вызывал setInterval(). Поэтому каждый раз вызывался всё больше и больше раз мой метод: на первом интервале один, на втором два, на третьем 4 и так далее... Тогда браузер и висел (не сразу, а со временем).

Отследите какие функции у вас работают, когда страница открыта. Лучше просто поставить breakpoint в начало каждого метода.

Answer (score 1):

Да процессор напрягается, да и память потихоньку подъедает. Видимо кривой слайдер.

UPD1: вот есть расширение для лисы, некоторым помогает https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leak-monitor/  А еще попробуйте, отключить автоматическое перелистывание и посмотрите на поведение. И можно потестить в разных браузерах, бывает, что некоторые не будем показывать пальцем на ИЕ не очень хорошо выполняют js

Comment: а в чём причина? можно ли это исправить, почему он ест память когда там крутится всего 5 картинок?

Comment: память съедается из-за того, что какие-то объекты не уничтожаются, а проц грузит неправильное использование таймера или слишком большое количество анимации.

Comment: а какие именно не знаете? полазаю тогда, сравню с оригиналом

Comment: к примеру в вашем скрипте для каждой итерации слайдера создаются какие-либо DOM элемты, которые не удаляются после

Comment: Не уверен насчет процессора, но вот оперативная память, хоть и достигает > 45мб - все время подчищается до уровня 33-42мб, по поводу "память потихоньку растет", так это, как-бы, логично, GC не будет же по поводу и без блочить IO.

Иными словами - утечки я не увидел ( chromium последней версии )

Кстати у вас там баг есть при ручном перелистывании слайдера

Comment: какой баг?

Answer (score 0):

Такое возникает из-за кривого анимирования ролика. Анимацию необходимо сделать правильно. Пинайте флешера.

Comment: это не флеш

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/index2.html
это оригинал, он работает правильно получается или тоже некорректно?

Comment: Оригинал работает правильно!

Comment: проверил, честно говоря загрузка ничем не отличалась от первой... если это не флеш тогда извиняйте.
Не знаю помежет нет но у меня кеширование в браузере выключено (лиса)